# How to add values in two different scope objects to a single scope object in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to merge values from 2 different scope objects to a single one.

```
$scope.a={
name: A;
}
$scope=b{
age:12;

}

$scope.x=angular.copy($scope.a,$scope.b);
```

or

```
$scope.x=angular.extend($scope.a,$scope.b);
```

or

```
$scope.x=angular.merge($scope.a,$scope.b);
```

This is not working. What I get is only the value of `$scope.a` assigned to `$scope.x`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("MyCtrl" , function($scope){
  $scope.x = {a:"",b:""};
  
  
  $scope.copy = function(a,b){
       $scope.x.a = angular.copy(a);
     $scope.x.b = angular.copy(b);
    }
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <form >   
  <input type="text" ng-model="a">
  <input type="text" ng-model="b">
  
    <input type="button" ng-click="copy(a,b)" value="copy">
 </form> 
  
  
  <pre>{{ x | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

you should change yuor `$scope.x` object. like to this.

```
$scope.x = {
             a:"",
             b:""
           }
```

then use angular copy

```
$scope.x.a = angular.copy($scope.a);
$scope.x.b = angular.copy($scope.b);
```

Comment: Sorry man Tryed it. But it didn't work. Still the data wont pass to the `$scope.x` I think its because `$scope.b` has 3 attributes. I'm not sure about that though. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: your question was vague. I think that you want to pass $scope.a and b to other variable like x.

Comment: yes thats right. I wanted to do that.  But the above code does not work when I try it. Sorry

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it. I used `angular.merge` like this,

`$scope.a = angular.merge($scope.b);`

this works

Comment: This assigns `b` to `a`.

Comment: It worked for me. I got all the values in `$scope.a` and `$scope.b` to `$scope.a`